# How to use several subprocess.check_output and avoid non-zero exit status 67

Tags: python, osx-mavericks

I'm at the beginning of learning python, so it may be something obvious. I'm trying to create a script that will change the desktop pictures in OS X 10.9 according to group membership.
If I only check for one thing, the script works. It's when I try to expend on it that I fail.
I've tried putting all the declarations before the if else, also tried it with if elif else.

How does one get python to use several subprocess.check_output in a row?

The script dies with this traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/SetDesktopImages/SetDesktopImages.py", line 36, in module
>       CheckStudentUser = subprocess.check_output(['dseditgroup', '-o' , 'checkmember', '-m', username, 'students'])
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dseditgroup', '-o', 'checkmember', '-m', 'root', 'students']' returned non-zero exit status 67

If I run the command itself, it is fine:

$ dseditgroup -o checkmember -m root students
no root is NOT a member of students

Here is my script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This script checks the user's membership to groups in order to set the Desktop Picture.

from AppKit import NSWorkspace, NSScreen
from Foundation import NSURL
import getpass
import subprocess

network_user_path = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Abstract.jpg"
ladmin_path = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Desert.jpg"
luser_path = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Flamingos.jpg"

# generate a fileURL
nu_file_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(network_user_path)
la_file_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(ladmin_path)
lu_file_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(luser_path)

username=getpass.getuser()
options = {}
ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()

CheckAdminUser = subprocess.check_output(['dseditgroup', '-o' , 'checkmember', '-m', username, 'admin'])
IsAdmin = subprocess.check_output(['echo', CheckAdminUser, '|', 'cut', '-d', '-f1', '|', 'awk', '{print $1}'])

if IsAdmin == 'yes':
    for screen in NSScreen.screens():
        (result, error) = ws.setDesktopImageURL_forScreen_options_error_(
                                                                     la_file_url, screen, options, None)
else:

    CheckStudentUser = subprocess.check_output(['dseditgroup', '-o' , 'checkmember', '-m', username, 'students'])
    IsStudent = subprocess.check_output(['echo', CheckStudentUser, '|', 'cut', '-d', '-f1', '|', 'awk', '{print $1}'])

if IsStudent == 'yes':
        for screen in NSScreen.screens():
            (result, error) = ws.setDesktopImageURL_forScreen_options_error_(
                                                                     nu_file_url, screen, options, None)
else:
    CheckLocalUser = subprocess.check_output(['dseditgroup', '-o' , 'checkmember', '-m', username, 'localaccounts'])
    IsLocal = subprocess.check_output(['echo', CheckLocalUser, '|', 'cut', '-d', '-f1', '|', 'awk', '{print $1}'])

if IsLocal == 'yes':
        for screen in NSScreen.screens():
            (result, error) = ws.setDesktopImageURL_forScreen_options_error_(
                                                                     lu_file_url, screen, options, None)
# not sure about this ending
else:
    exit0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-zero exit status means there was an error, or other abnormal exit.

Its clear from your command output that there *was* an error, in fact the error message is shown as a result, the difference is your shell suppresses the error code.  To see what the exit code was, type `echo "$?"`, here is an example:

```
$ dseditgroup -o checkmember -m root students
Group not found.
$ echo "$?"
64
```

Here the command returned the exit code `64`.  The output was written to `stderr` the standard error buffer.  In the shell it looks the same because it will print both `stdout` (standard output) and `stderr`, but notice if I redirect `stderr` to a file, you don't see any output:

```
$ dseditgroup -o checkmember -m root students 2&> ~/out.txt
$ echo "$?"
64
$ cat ~/out.txt
Group not found.
```

You can avoid the exception by capturing any output that is written to `stderr` in your script. This is also detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
check_admin_user = subprocess.check_output(
                     ['dseditgroup', '-o' , 'checkmember', '-m', username, 'admin'],
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                   )
```

I also changed your variable names as per the [Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and pointing out the naming conventions.

Here's the two possible outputs to the command:  
    $ dseditgroup -o checkmember -m root students  
    no root is NOT a member of students  
    $ dseditgroup -o checkmember -m root admin  
    yes root is a member of admin    
Capturing the output to stderr did not help: the 1st check goes, it stops at the second (check_student_user) with the same error as before (return non-zero exit status 67).
If I only use one check, the script works, it's the adding of the other checks that seem problematic.

Comment: You need to add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to _every_ call you make.  You also don't need to do all this sed / awk business as you can take the output of the command and figure out the result in Python by using `.split()`.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to get it to run, and I also modified the awk bit, getting rid of it and using substrings in python directly, since I only need the beginning of the answer I used check_admin_user[:3]. Next I'll learn about .split to get it out.